# how to import async modules with JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, import, webdriver-io

Maybe i asked wrong question.

i'm trying to test some site, and have this throw in terminal

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf5IB.png)

it's obvious, that function returns uuid after it was called in code.
it work's normaly, when i take element right in code, so the reason, i think, in uncorrect import

here's my code :

file.js

```
describe('final homeTask', () => {
    it('firstassigment', async () => {
        let mainPage = require('../page/main.pageHW.js')
        await browser.url('https://github.com/')

        let signUpButton = await mainPage.topSignUpBtn()
        await signUpButton.click()
    })
})
```

main.pageHW.js

```
class MainPage {
    get topSignUpBtn () { return $('a.btn-mktg:nth-child(1)') }
}

module.exports = new MainPage()
```

Comment: Sounds like you should declare `topSignUpBtn` as an async function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem with Javascript, not about `webdriver`, you are using a property in the MainPage class:

```
  class MainPage {
      /// The get word make it a property
      get topSignUpBtn () { return $('a.btn-mktg:nth-child(1)') }
  }

  module.exports = new MainPage()
```

That means you DON'T need parentheses to use it, so, replace:

```
  let signUpButton = await mainPage.topSignUpBtn()
```

By

```
  let signUpButton = await mainPage.topSignUpBtn;
```

Also, the property doesn't need the `await` clause.

If you want more info you can check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).